# Trying to get the height and width of Chrome application window from Windows API?

Tags: c++, windows, google-chrome, winapi

I'm trying to get the dimensions of Chrome windows from a console app in Windows and I seem to be having problems getting it from the Win32 API.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProcMy(HWND hwnd,LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD lpdwProcessId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd,&lpdwProcessId);
    if(lpdwProcessId==lParam)
    {
        g_HWND=hwnd;
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    charArray = "chrome.exe";

    // getting process id from name
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
    {
        while (Process32Next(snapshot, &entry) == TRUE)
        {
            CString strProcessName = entry.szExeFile;

            //if (stricmp(entry.szExeFile, charArray) == 0)
            if (strProcessName == charArray)
            {  
                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);
                EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProcMy, entry.th32ProcessID);
                // g_HWND now has HWND for the process chrome.exe.
                hWindowFromProcess = g_HWND;
                int result = 0, result2 = 0;
                result = GetWindowRect(g_HWND, &g_Rect);

                LONG  nWidth = g_Rect.right - g_Rect.left;
                LONG  nHeight = g_Rect.bottom - g_Rect.top;
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I get the results from the RECT struct, I keep getting values that are way off.  For example, when I have the window fully maximized in a 1920 x 1080 screen I get a width of 71 pixels and a height of 16 pixels. I also noticed that no matter the size it change the window, the values for the RECT stay the same. If I test with another window (like cmd.exe) I get correct RECT values.

So I'm assuming that the rendering of the browser is done by a method other than the WinAPI. I've seen some articles about getting the browser dimensions using javascript, but I need this information from a windows application.

Comment: Two things wrong with your approach. Firstly, `EnumWindows` enumerates all top-level windows in the system. Chrome probably uses lots of windows, so simply picking the first one you find is not enough to know it's the one you want. Secondly, have you ever looked at task manager when Chrome is running? It creates about 4000 different processes. So not only are you probably finding the wrong window, you're most likely finding the wrong window from the wrong process.

Comment: Hi Jonathan,
I think that Process32Next() does go through all the Chrome processes. I checked the Chrome task manager (shift-esc) on the browser and I match up with the number of iterations in the while loop as those reported in the browser task manager. (i.e. 2 processes + 1 per extra tab when all extensions are turned off.) Additionally, I counted the number of processes running while Chrome is running and when it is off and the numbers jibe.

Comment: Clearly you aren't getting the right window. Use Spy++ to find the right one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome uses a couple of invisible windows, you are supposed to skip those. Chrome windows have their own classname `"Chrome_WidgetWin_1"`, it can be used to find the window (you can find this information from Spy++ tool)

Also try to avoid the `T` macro and global variables. Here is an example in Unicode:

```
int wmain()
{
    HWND hwnd = NULL;
    for (;;)
    {
        hwnd = FindWindowEx(0, hwnd, L"Chrome_WidgetWin_1", 0);
        if (!hwnd) 
            break;

        if (!IsWindowVisible(hwnd))
            continue;                     

        RECT rect;
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
        int w = rect.right - rect.left;
        int h = rect.bottom - rect.top;
        cout << w << ", " << h << "\n";
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```